# Closed Div by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

### HTML Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .msg_body
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">

    </script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".msg_head").click(function () {
                $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle();
            })

            $(".msg_headRoot").click(function () {
                $(this).next(".msg_bodyRoot").slideToggle();
            })

        .toggle(function () {
            $(this).children("span").text("[+]");
        }, function () {
            $(this).children("span").text("[-]");
        });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="msg_headRoot" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <p class="msg_headRoot" style="margin: 3px; line-height: 20px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">
            <span>[+]&nbsp;</span>Root
        </p>
        <div class="msg_bodyRoot">
            <div class="msg_head" style="cursor: pointer;">
                <p class="msg_head" style="margin: 3px; line-height: 20px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">
                    <span>[+]&nbsp;</span>Hello
                </p>
                <div class="msg_body">
                    Div text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Query

Right now it is keeping the div opened. I want to keep the div closed by default and user should click the plus to open it.

### EDIT

Forgot to mention the root div. I have actually one nested div. I meant on click the plus of outer dive should open the inner div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
.msg_body, .msg_bodyRoot {display: none;}​
```

Updated JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var toggler = function(elem) {
        elem.slideToggle(500, function() {
            if (elem.is(':visible')) {
                elem.parent().find("p:first > span").text("[-]");
            } else {
                elem.parent().find("p:first > span").text("[+]");
            }
        });
    };
    $('div.msg_headRoot').click(function(e) {
        toggler($(this).children(".msg_bodyRoot"));
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
    $("div.msg_head").click(function(e) {
        toggler($(this).children(".msg_body"));
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N9E9b/2/

Comment: Don't forget to swap the text() functions round so + and - are correct.

Comment: Edits checked. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add some CSS to your markup:

```
.msg_body { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semi-colon, and no toggle on the inner part. I made some assumptions on my part that the root should work with its child and the inner with its child.  I surely hope I have not made an oversimplification of what you want here.

EDIT: REMOVED BAD CODE THAT HAD BUGS

Just to follow up with the simpler: (and fix a minor issue with +/- text in prior version)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".msg_head,.msg_headRoot").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle();
        var clickp = $(this).children("span:contains('+')");
        var clickm = $(this).children("span:contains('-')");
        clickp.text("[-]");
        clickm.text("[+]");
    });
});


<div>
    <p class="msg_headRoot"><span>[-]&nbsp;</span>Root</p>
    <div class="msg_body">
        <p class="msg_head"><span>[+]&nbsp;</span>Hello</p>
        <div class="msg_body">Div text</div> 
    </div>
</div>

.msg_headRoot,.msg_head{margin: 3px; line-height: 20px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; cursor:pointer;}
.msg_body div.msg_body{display:none;}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ykRaY/3/

Comment: Note: this can probably be even a bit more tight but should get you started - if my assumptions are correct.

Comment: When you wrote `$(".msg_head,.msg_headRoot").click(function() {
` where did you handle to toggle the root div ?

Comment: @PankajGarg The are both handled in the same place - it works because the selector looks for the NEXT INSTANCE of the .msg_body class - the root and the inner both have a "next" one of those, and they are NOT the same one - read up on .next() here: http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: @PankajGarg - I realize you have your answer but for others, the last edit/example should be good to go.